# Pass array from php to javascript method

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, methods

In my php i make a db call, and the result is

```
$options = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Now, I want to make a javascript method call and pass this function. My javascript method looks like

```
function myFunction(options){
//iterate over each option
}
```

and what I am doing is

```
<?php echo "<script>myFunction('".$options."')</script>";
```

This gives me error on my server that I am doing array to string conversion.

I thought javascript determined the datatype on runtime and hence I'll be ok with this. can someone please tell me the correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What's that have to do with the fact that you're trying to make PHP spit out an array as a string?, Why not just pass as json object? `json_encode($options)`

Comment: @ksealey So, how do I make my php spit out an array as an array?

Comment: Turn that array into a string representation of a java array and assign it to a javascript variable, then pass that variable, or do as I noted in the edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have PHP print out an array JavaScript can use, you can convert the array to JSON string and then echo that directly.

```
# Convert PHP array to JSON array
$json_options = json_encode($options);

# Echo JavaScript and JSON without single quotes
<?php echo "<script>myFunction(".$json_options.")</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass a php array into javascript function as array. However you can pass it as stated by Grokify or you can pass it directly assign into your a javascript variable if your function is on same page by giving into php environment.

```
function myFunction(){
    var options = <?php echo json_encode($options); ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, declare your JS function.

```
function myFunction(options){
 options = JSON.parse(options);

 for(var i=0; i<= options.length; i++){
    console.log(options[i]);
  }
}
```

And in your PHP side, convert array into JSON and pass it to JS function

```
$json = json_encode($options);

# Echo JavaScript and JSON without single quotes
<?php echo "<script>myFunction(".$json.")</script>";
```